# VoiceLayer iOS obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am integrating VoiceLayer library for "walk-talky" purpose in an app. 
I got the following error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_utf8_nextCharSafeBody",
>   referenced from:
>         -[SRWebSocket _innerPumpScanner] in VoiceLayer(SRWebSocket.o)

Added voice layer library in Build Phases.
-ObjC flag is there in Other Linker flags

Comment: how can i resolve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `libicucore.dylib` to my project and solved the build issue.

Answer (score 1):

It  seems the library doesn't offer 64bit ...

under Build Settings remove 64bit as a valid arch -- that should let you run it and make it work on any OS :)

[image]

---

**be aware that 64bit is becoming mandatory for the App Store, so get an updated library**

Comment: what is? this? nah .. then it wouldn't try to build arm64